# how to get java to run an application and when user closes the application, java runs another process in mac or windows

Tags: java, process

Hi all
i m trying to write a java program to open an application on a mac, wait in the background until the user closes the application, then the java program performs another task. is there a way to know when the user has closed the application started by java?

thanks

Comment: if you know the PID (process ID) it should be no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***is there a way to know when the user has closed the application started by java?***

Sure, here's how:

1. Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [`Runtime.exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to get hold of a [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).
2. Start the process by doing `process.start()`.
3. Then call [`proccess.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) to block until the external program terminates.

This should work fine on Mac and Windows systems.

---

**Example:**

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/emacs");

Process proc = pb.start();     // start external program

proc.waitFor();                // wait for it to terminate

performAnotherTask();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i tried it and the program just ignores the waitfor and goes straight to the next task.

Comment: Did you do `start()` properly? Did you get a `proc` object back? How does the program you're starting work? Does it in turn fork a new process and terminate itself?

Comment: here is the code,sorry for the formatting, i dont kn ow how to make it appear properly                                                        try {                                                                             Process proc =  new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "c/temp/the.doc").start();
proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("it works");

Comment: What happens if you just try with say notepad.exe? (use the full path to be sure) Does that work?

Comment: it works great with notepad, no issues, but it fails on mac. it just ignore the proc.waitfor(); and move on to the next task

Comment: Since it works with notepad.exe there's something fishy going on here. As the answer to your original question here basically is `proc.waitFor()` I don't think your current problem gets as much attention here. If I where you, I would formulate a new question, stating what you've tried, what it works for and what it doesn't work for. That way you'll probably get more attention and hopefully some better answers. (Seems like a generic problem too, so the community would benefit from such question / answer.) (Post the link to the new follow-up question here, and I'll have a look at it.)

Comment: @Arphadax: Better code samples add to the question, instead of a comment. In this case, add a full sample Java code which does not work on Mac to the question. (It may depend on the application started by you.)

Comment: Since this question has basically evolved into a new question, I would recommend @Arphadax to post a new question. Edits and updates that turn the question into a new question is seldom appreciated. Adding a link to the new question (in this question), and a link to this question (in the new question) may still be a good idea though.